# How to Get the HTTP Response Size in Java (in Bytes)

Tags: java, http, request, response

I have a Java Servlet and the corresponding `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` objects. I need to find out the size, in bytes, of the response being sent back to the client. Simple question, but it's surprisingly difficult and I couldn't find any good examples.

First of all, the `HttpServletResponse` class has a method that returns a `ServletOutputStream`, but no size/length info.

```
HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()  :  ServletOutputStream
```

Some people point to the Apache Commons' `CountingOutputStream` and that you can "wrap" or "forward" that to the main output while consuming data, there was no actual code given in the answer and I couldn't get it to work. Any solutions with specific code examples would be appreciated. Thanks.

The servlet still needs to work as usual, it just needs to capture the Response Size on each cycle.

Comment: What do you need to do with the response size, and when? Before or after the response has been sent? Are you trying to use this number to set the HTTP `Content-Length` header?

Comment: I'm sure there was the same questions somewhere around

Comment: There was the same question around, with no specific code. I would like to see specific code that works.

Answer (score 4):

Since the response is written continuously, you have two options:

- wrap `HttpServletResponse` in order to return your own `OutputStream` wrapper, which in turn counts the bytes written to it
- use the tomcat [Valve logging](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html)

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't enough information for me. I need to see specific code that I can run and that will work.

Comment: this is not a "write my code" site. I told you how to do it, you should just write the code. If you don't understand something, be specific