# Getting Size of Http request and response

Tags: android, tomcat, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I am study about doPost and get method to send data from android app to tomcat server.

I am trying to check the size of http request and response because I am sure that request and response was sending data and catching data from tomcat server.

I used this example ,

> http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-determine-the-content-length-of-a-request.html

to check the contents length.

After I get contents length, i get two questions

**First**, contents-length represents whole size of http request  ?

if it is not, then how can i check the size of http request (by bytes)?

**second** , I am still having a trouble to getting size of response ?

I tried

> [How to Get the HTTP Response Size in Java (in Bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708560/how-to-get-the-http-response-size-in-java-in-bytes)
>
> [Determine size of HTTP Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435351/determine-size-of-http-response)

but i was getting error to get size of http response

is there any way to get size of http response ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. No, it is not the size of the whole request. It is the length of the message body, excluding status line and headers.
2. Not all servers provide the content length. If you use chunked transfer encoding, the content length cannot be determined without downloading the whole response. If the server sends the "Content-Length" header, you can get the size of the message body. You need to hook the socket stream to get the actual (full) response size.

Comment: user1561072// thanks for answering my question. Then.. how can i check the size of incoming and outgoing data ?

Comment: @DcRedwing How do you make the request? HttpClient on Android?